# Computing $\int\frac{dy}{cy-by^2}$ from $\int\frac{dx}{a^2-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Rewrite $cy-by^2$ as $a^2-x^2$, with $x=\sqrt{b}y-\frac{c}{2\sqrt{b}}$ and
>   $a=$_____. Substitute for $a$ and $x$ in the integral taken from tables, to obtain the y-integral in the text:
>   $$\int\frac{dx}{a^2-x^2}=\frac{1}{2a}\ln\frac{a+x}{a-x}\\
> \int\frac{dy}{cy-by^2}=\frac{1}{c}\ln\frac{y}{c-by}$$

From $cy-by^2=a^2-\left(\sqrt{b}y-\frac{c}{2\sqrt{b}}\right)^2$, we get $a=\frac{c}{2\sqrt{b}}$. Substituting $a$ and $x$ in the formula for $\int\frac{dx}{a^2-x^2}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{dx}{a^2-x^2}&=\frac{1}{2a}\ln\frac{a+x}{a-x}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{b}}{c}\ln\frac{\sqrt{b}y}{\frac{c}{\sqrt{b}}-\sqrt{b}y}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{b}}{c}\ln\frac{by}{c-by}
\end{align}
$$
This looks very similar to the desired result, but it seems very difficult to get rid of $\sqrt{b}$ and $b$. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Remember that $\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{b}\mathrm{d}y$ and also remember that the integration constant can be $-\frac{\ln b}{c}$